# tr:not(:first-child) being ignored for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an HTML table generated via SQL and PHP. There is a JS `onClick` event at the `<table>` level.

I am trying to set it up so my first row (first row below the `<TH>`) and first three columns are not part of the event. These rows/columns are forms and not part of the active data.

I have the below script and the `TD`'s are being successfully ignored but I cannot seem to remove the `onClick` alert form the first `TR` no matter how I modify the code.

Everything else works 100% as expected. I am aware that this might not be the best or most efficient way to to what I need, but it's all I have managed to put together that works as expected so far.

```
$('table tr:not(:first-child) td:not(:nth-child(-n+3))')
  .unbind()
  .click(function(clickSpot){
       var clickID = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3)').text();
       alert(clickID);
})
```

Comment: Well, it seem me typing this out helping me to solve it. Correct me if i'm incorrect but it seems :first-child in this case was choosing the <TH> row. I replaced it with nth-child(2) and it works like a champ.

Comment: You  could post that as an answer if it has solved the problem.

Comment: Usually I put the table header row into `<thead>` and table data rows into a `<tbody>`, this clears things up in CSS and jQuery selectors and has its benefits in DOM navigation as well.

Comment: `$('table tr:not(:first-child) td:not(:nth-child(-n+3))')` better as `$('table').find(' tr:not(:first-child)').find('td:not(:nth-child(-n+3))')` due to the right to left selection in sizzle engine.

Comment: Just to point out, `clickSpot` is the same as "event" here, might be better to rename it. Was that actually your intent here?

Comment: it started with a $(clickSpot.target) but i could not use any of the selectors after that. That changed $(this) to be able to add proper selectors and i just never pulled clickSpot out because i was still working the other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using `thead` and `tbody` since it seems you want to use the `tbody` here - OR move those "forms" from the table, put it above that, then use `$('table').find('tbody').find('td:not(:nth-child(-n+3))')`  Better might be to simply add classes to either the things you want or those you do not want.

Unbind is deprecated so I used `off` and `on` here.

<strike>Example, add classes to the table rows you wish to target.</strike>

After understanding your question a bit, I simply used the tbody and skipped all td that has an input - which it seems is what you really desire, and makes this work if you change your table to have more checkboxes.

```js
$('table').find('tbody')
   .on('click','td:not(:has("input"))',function(event){
      var clickID = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(3).text();
      alert(clickID);
});
```

```css
tr td {border: solid green 1px;}
tr.useme td {border:solid blue 1px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header content 1</th>
      <th>Header content 2</th>
      <th>Header content 3</th>
      <th>Header content N</th>
      <th>Header content N</th>
      <th>Header content N</th>
      <th>Header content N</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Body content 1</td>
      <td>Body content 2</td>
      <td>Body content 3</td>
      <td>Body content N</td>
      <td>Body content N</td>
      <td>Body content N</td>
      <td>Body content N</td>
    </tr>
     <tr class='useme'>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Body content 3</td>
      <td>Body content N</td>
      <td>Body content N</td>
      <td>Body content N</td>
      <td>Body content N</td>
   </tr>
     <tr class='useme'>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Body content 2</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Body content N</td>
      <td>Body content N</td>
      <td>Body content N</td>
      <td>Body content N</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To attach to the table example: might have to change the `td` to target specific ones.  The point is the event handler attaches to the `tbody` here, adding rows makes no difference, they still get the events.  No need to re-execute this on each table row addition as long as the `tbody` stays in place.

```
$('table').find('tbody')
   .on('click','td',function(event){
      var clickID = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(3).text();
      alert(clickID);
});
```

Original:

```
$('table').find('tbody')
   .find('tr.useme').find('td')
   .off('click').on('click',function(event){
      var clickID = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(3).text();
      alert(clickID);
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the table is dynamic. It can have one TR or 80 TR's and i want them all to act the same way so adding classes per TR would not help in this case. Thanks very much for the suggestions about how to do the selections though.

Comment: So it might be better to separate your "form" portion and the "data" portion perhaps?  (or simply add classes to the dynamic table) - not sure actually why you `unbind, off` then re-add the event handler, but that is out of scope for your question as worded.

Comment: The forms are text/dropdown filters. That's where the inputs are entered to create the change in the table. Think like an excel table. You type in the header and the column filters itself accordingly. The unbind() was added after-the-fact because on the second row i was getting two alerts, on the third row i was getting 3 alerts, etc. In research that was the easiest fix to stop it adding multiple instances.

Comment: Ah so the table exists, and then rows are added?  In that case, I would attach the event handler to the table rather than the TD and only run this code once...will add example

Comment: Yes sir. I can add it here but the PHP, SQL is quite cumbersome. The TH and first TR with the forms are static. The portions lower than that are added on the fly depending on the results of the SQL query. https://imgur.com/FgFjA2w this is the page as it sits now. The rows with data are autogenerated.